# R:lmrob in robustbase package: why is robust SE lower for a smaller model? Also, what does R^2 here mean?

Tags: r, regression, robust

I have the two following models:

```
require(robustbase)
data(stackloss)
d1 <- lmrob(stack.loss~., data =  stackloss)
d2 <- lmrob(stack.loss~Air.Flow+Water.Temp, data =  stackloss)
```

No I look at the follwing two summaries:

```
summary(d1)

Call:
lmrob(formula = stack.loss ~ ., data = stackloss)
 \--> method = "MM"
Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-10.50974  -1.43819  -0.09134   1.02503   7.23113 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -41.52462    5.29780  -7.838 4.82e-07 ***
Air.Flow      0.93885    0.11743   7.995 3.68e-07 ***
Water.Temp    0.57955    0.26296   2.204   0.0416 *  
Acid.Conc.   -0.11292    0.06989  -1.616   0.1246    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Robust residual standard error: 1.912 
Multiple R-squared:  0.9593,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9521 
Convergence in 17 IRWLS iterations
```

and

```
summary(d2)

Call:
lmrob(formula = stack.loss ~ Air.Flow + Water.Temp, data = stackloss)
 \--> method = "MM"
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10.5579  -1.4620   0.2749   1.3708   7.4623 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -47.9487    10.7127  -4.476 0.000292 ***
Air.Flow      0.8964     0.1540   5.820 1.63e-05 ***
Water.Temp    0.5378     0.2732   1.968 0.064614 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Robust residual standard error: 1.732 
Multiple R-squared:  0.9589,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9543 
Convergence in 27 IRWLS iterations
```

In my view, it it odd that the robust SE has a higher value for the more complex model than the simpler model.

Btw, how is the R-squared calculated for lmrob? Is it is the usual calculation of sum of squares of the raw residuals divided by the total corrected sum of squares or is there any robustness involved (beyond the fits of the coefficients)?

I don't see this mentioned anywhere in the help for lmrob.fit. And the following calculation throws up a very different value (so the raw calculation guess on my part is not correct):

```
sum(d2$residuals^2)/(sum((stackloss$stack.loss - mean(stackloss$stack.loss))^2))
[1] 0.1131587
```

Finally,  does the hat matrix include observations that are deemed outliers?

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question to be more R-specific. Hopefully this expalins more my question and i still pertinent for this forum? Thanks again!

Comment: Even at this point, I'd suggest posting to CV. SO is place for focused programming questions. Questions on the relative sizes of SEs and the calculation of r-squared seems like stat methodology.

Comment: Robust regression undermines drop of some unusual observations. So you build the model and calculate R^2 on transformed (reduced in size) sample so it is no surprise that determination coefficient may become lower.

Comment: Thanks, Bogdan! Does this mean that two models can be compared using R-squared or the adjusted R-squared? Edited question to also ask about the hat matrix.